# Writing data from within Kubernetes Pod to host

Tags: redis, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes redis Pod, which I need to backup/restore its data through dump.rdb. When restore, I put dump.rdb under /data and launch the pod with this config:

```
containers:
  - name: redis
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /data/
        name: data-volume
volumes:
- name: data-volume
  hostPath:
    path: /data/
    type: Directory
```

It can see the dump.rdb from host's /data dir, but when Redis saves any changes in the Pod, it only updated the /data dir within the Pod not the host. My goal is to be able to backup the dump.rdb on the host, so I need the dump.rdb on the host to get updated too. What am I missing here?

Comment: How many worker nodes do you have? Are you looking at the same host that pod is running on? If you are looking at the same host and same hostPath as mounted then: "It can see the dump.rdb from host's /data dir, but when Redis saves any changes in the Pod, it only updated the /data dir within the Pod not the host" doesn't make much sense. Can you try to write to that folder on host and observer change in pod? Can you "touch" file on pod and observer change on host?

Comment: I see, so I'm on the wrong node. I have one k8smaster and two workers. After a touch in the pod, and looking through all hosts, I found the file I touched on one of the hosts, and the dump.rdb there appears to be updated too. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, you could also get all node info directly with kubectl get pods -o wide (and -n for namespace if not in default) and then no need to shuffle through active worker nodes. As sidenote, This is something to take into account in your setup, since during regular "rescheduling" or pod restarts you might see changes in data (since hostFolder can and will be eventually used from some other node while up-to-that-point data will be left on previously used one). If you use hostPath, make sure that data is either ephemeral or pod scheduled to specific node that holds data directory.

Answer (score 0):

[Const`s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9663586/const) question helps to find the solution for [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908505/joe).

[Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908505/joe)  missed the place where the file was stored.

My suggestion: try to use NFS volume for storing and restoring backups, it may be easier than using the  `hostPath`